# Zend 2.3.1 cannot run on server

Tags: php, zend-framework

I developed a website at local by Zend Framework 2.3.1, but when I upload it on production (PHP 5.3.3) it displayed blank page.
An elder developer debugged and said that maybe error occurred because of ZF version. He has a website on that server which is developed by Zend Framework 2.2.5 and it runs OK.

I copied all ZF 2.2.5 library into my website, but I received these error:

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of Application\View\Helper\Custommenu::renderNormalMenu() should be compatible with Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu::renderNormalMenu(Zend\Navigation\AbstractContainer $container, $ulClass, $indent, $minDepth, $maxDepth, $onlyActive, $escapeLabels, $addClassToListItem) in D:\WebTool\module\Application\src\Application\view\Helper\Custommenu.php on line 16

Warning: Missing argument 9 for Application\View\Helper\Custommenu::renderNormalMenu(), called in D:\WebTool\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu.php on line 219 and defined in D:\WebTool\module\Application\src\Application\view\Helper\Custommenu.php on line 85

Fatal error: Zend\Navigation\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Bad method call: Unknown method Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc::getTextDomain in D:\WebTool\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper.php on line 169
```

Is there any solution to solved this problems?

Comment: Have you read the error messages? It's because of someone declared `Application\View\Helper\Custommenu::renderNormalMenu()` in an incompatible to v2.2.5 way

Comment: @zerkms: yes, I did. I tried to fix it (rewrite the method, copy some files/methods from Zend 2.3.1). It does not work.

Comment: just to clarify. You have implemented something using v2.3.1 and it does not work with v2.2.5. So, why don't you install the required version of zend framework then? I'm lost in understanding why you develop and deploy for different versions.